# .Net 5 blazor server app property is null in razor but has data after webapi call

Tags: razor, blazor-server-side

I am coding a .Net 5 Blazor server side app and - sorry if I am using the wrong terminology - can't seem to pin down why the razor page's object/property is null, yet the code-behind method that populates that object/property contains data from a webApi. I am trying to use the repository pattern, dto objects, dependency injection, webapi, and efcore.

In Startup.cs > ConfigureServices() I have:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IDocumentNumbersDataService, DocumentNumbersDataService>
            (client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44323/"));
```

For the UI I have Home.razor:

````
@page "/Home"
<form method="get">
<div class="input-group-append">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SearchDocumentNumbers">Search</button>
</div></form>

@if (DocumentNumbers == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    ```
    show table of document numbers using foreach()
    ```
}
````

and its code-behind Home.cs:

```
public partial class Home
{
    public IEnumerable<DocumentNumberDto> DocumentNumbers { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string ProjNumber { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public IDocumentNumbersDataService DocumentNumbersDataService { get; set; }
    protected async Task<IEnumerable<DocumentNumberDto>> SearchDocumentNumbers()
    {
        ProjNumber = "1012100100";
        var DocumentNumbers = await DocumentNumbersDataService.GetDocumentNumbersAsync(ProjNumber); //DocumentNumbers gets populated with Dto objects
    }
}
```

The call to GetDocumentNumbersAsync() in DocumentNumberDataService is:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DocumentNumberDto>> GetDocumentNumbersAsync(string ProjNumber)
    {
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<DocumentNumberDto>>
            (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/documentnumbers/{ProjNumber}"), 
                new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    }
```

The problem: DocumentNumbers property is null in Home.razor even though the `IEnumerable<DocumentNumbersDto> DocumentNumbers` is populated via...

```
    var DocumentNumbers = await DocumentNumbersDataService.GetDocumentNumbersAsync(ProjNumber);
```

I suspect I overlooked something simple.

Comment: If I read this correctly you're saying if you changed the line in `SearchDocumentNumbers` to  `var docs = await DocumentNumbersDataService.GetDocumentNumbersAsync(ProjNumber);` will return a set of `IEnumerable<DocumentNumberDto>`, but the class property `DocumentNumbers` isn't being populated, or doesn't appear to be populated because nothing is displayed?

Comment: Yes, I believe you understand the problem I am having...Home.razor doesn't show the items in DocumentNumbers. I changed the method to `protected async Task<IEnumerable<DocumentNumberDto>> SearchDocumentNumbers()` and changing the call to the data service to `var DocumentNumbers = await DocumentNumbersDataService.GetDocumentNumbersAsync(ProjNumber);` and the DocumentNumber var does get the data, but in Home.razor, DocumentNumbers is null.
Not sure why but in Edge Developer Tools, I am seeing a status 101 Switching Protocols for _blazor?id=someIdCode

Comment: `var DocumentNumbers` in `SearchDocumentNumbers` is a local variable.  If it populated when you call `SearchDocumentNumbers`, you can assign it to `this.DocumentNumbers` which is the class property in `SearchDocumentNumbers`.  You're `async` with `Tasks` so the automatic `StateHasChanged` won't get called until `SearchDocumentNumbers` completes.

Comment: Sorry for not replying for quite a while...thanks for your feedback. When I click the Search button, if the button is `<input type="submit">` it does not show the documents successfully retrieved from the webapi, even if I assign the results from the webapi to `this.DocumentNumbers`, but if the button is `<input type="button">` it works! So, yes, some progress, but I don't understand why `<input type="submit">` doesn't work the way I coded it - I am missing something that should pass control back to the razor page or something like that.